# DMA transfer corrupted by another channel (ATSAMC21)

Tags: microcontroller, cortex-m, dma, atmel, crc16

I want to use DAM transfer for calculating CRC with ATSAMC21G17A MCU (E-revision).

I have already implemented 2 independent DMA channels controlling UART transfer, they are working good, I have no problems with them.

Now it's time to get CRC calculating working to calculate CRC of the Flash memory. I just use one timer to generate triggering events for DMA, I know the size of my firmware and just want to get it working. Timer works with period of 100usec.

But it doesn't really work, I get errors with another channels after starting DMA channel with CRC calculation, transfer process of another channel can be interrupted and doesn't work afterwards. It means it could transfer only some bytes, but not all of them. What am I doing wrong?

I have already read the whole errata about my MCU and don't find anything similar. I don't use link descriptors.

Here is my source code:

DMA initialization:

```
volatile bool DMA_TransferComplete[DMA_CHANNELS_NUM];

static DmacDescriptor dma_descr[DMA_CHANNELS_NUM]  __attribute__((aligned(16))) SECTION_DMAC_DESCRIPTOR;
static DmacDescriptor writeback[DMA_CHANNELS_NUM] __attribute__((aligned(16))) SECTION_DMAC_DESCRIPTOR;
static DmacDescriptor descriptor  __attribute__((aligned(16))) SECTION_DMAC_DESCRIPTOR;

/** \brief Initialize DMA module
 *
 * \return Nothing
 *
 */
void DMA_Init(void)
{
  uint8_t i;

  MCLK->AHBMASK.reg |= MCLK_AHBMASK_DMAC;

  DMAC->CTRL.reg &= ~DMAC_CTRL_DMAENABLE;
  DMAC->CTRL.reg = DMAC_CTRL_SWRST;

  DMAC->BASEADDR.reg = (uint32_t)dma_descr;
  DMAC->WRBADDR.reg = (uint32_t)writeback;

  DMAC->CTRL.reg = DMAC_CTRL_DMAENABLE | DMAC_CTRL_LVLEN(0xf);

  for (i = 0; i < DMA_CHANNELS_NUM; i++)
    DMA_TransferComplete[i] = true;

 NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMAC_IRQn);
 NVIC_SetPriority(DMAC_IRQn, 1);
}
```

Setup for DMA channel:

```
/** \brief Setup DMA transfer for selected channel
 *
 * \param [in] channel Number of the channel to act
 * \param [in] settings Pointer to TDmaSettings structure with DMA settings
 * \return Nothing
 *
 */
void DMA_SetupChannel(uint8_t channel, TDmaSettings *settings)
{
  uint16_t btctrlVal;

  if (channel >= DMA_CHANNELS_NUM)
    return;

  /**< Setup channel */
  DMAC->CHID.reg = DMAC_CHID_ID(channel);
  DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg &= ~DMAC_CHCTRLA_ENABLE;
  DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg = DMAC_CHCTRLA_SWRST;
  DMAC->SWTRIGCTRL.reg &= (uint32_t)(~(1 << channel));

  if (settings->trig_src == 0)
    DMAC->CHCTRLB.reg = DMAC_CHCTRLB_LVL(settings->priority) | DMAC_CHCTRLB_TRIGACT_BLOCK;
  else
    DMAC->CHCTRLB.reg = DMAC_CHCTRLB_LVL(settings->priority) | DMAC_CHCTRLB_TRIGSRC(settings->trig_src) | DMAC_CHCTRLB_TRIGACT_BEAT;
  /**< Enable interrupts */
  DMAC->CHINTENSET.reg = DMAC_CHINTENSET_MASK;
  /**< Prepare descriptor block */
  descriptor.DESCADDR.reg = 0;          // only one block to transfer, so 0
  descriptor.BTCNT.reg = settings->len;
  btctrlVal = DMAC_BTCTRL_VALID | DMAC_BTCTRL_BEATSIZE(settings->beat_size);
  descriptor.DSTADDR.reg = (uint32_t)settings->dst_addr;
  if (settings->dst_inc == true)
  {
    descriptor.DSTADDR.reg += settings->len;
    btctrlVal |= DMAC_BTCTRL_DSTINC;
  }
  descriptor.SRCADDR.reg = (uint32_t)settings->src_addr;
  if (settings->src_inc == true)
  {
    descriptor.SRCADDR.reg += settings->len;
    btctrlVal |= DMAC_BTCTRL_SRCINC;
  }
  descriptor.BTCTRL.reg = btctrlVal;

  memcpy(&dma_descr[channel], &descriptor, sizeof(DmacDescriptor));
}
```

Interrupt function for detection of "transfer complete" event:

```
/**< Interrupt for DMA transfer completion */
void DMAC_Handler(void)
{
  uint8_t channel;
  uint8_t old_channel;
  uint32_t res;

  /**< Get old channel number */
  old_channel = DMAC->CHID.reg;
  res = DMAC->INTSTATUS.reg;
  /**< Processing all affected channels */
  for (channel = 0; channel < DMA_CHANNELS_NUM; channel++)
  {
    if (res & (1 << channel))
    {
      /**< Set transfer complete flag */
      DMA_TransferComplete[channel] = true;
      /**< Select channel to work with */
      DMAC->CHID.reg = DMAC_CHID_ID(channel);
      /**< Clear all flags for DMA channel */
      DMAC->CHINTFLAG.reg = (DMAC_CHINTENCLR_TCMPL | DMAC_CHINTENCLR_TERR | DMAC_CHINTENCLR_SUSP);
      /**< Disable DMA transfer */
      DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg &= ~DMAC_CHCTRLA_ENABLE;
    }
  }
  DMAC->CHID.reg = old_channel;
}
```

Starting DMA transfer:

```
/** \brief Start DMA transfer, channel should be already initialized
 *
 * \param [in] channel Number of the channel to act
 * \return Nothing
 *
 */
void DMA_StartChannel(uint8_t channel)
{
  if (channel >= DMA_CHANNELS_NUM)
    return;

  /**< Setup channel */
  DMAC->CHID.reg = DMAC_CHID_ID(channel);
  if (DMA_TransferComplete[channel] == false)
    DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg &= ~DMAC_CHCTRLA_ENABLE;

  /**< Start DMA transfer */
  DMA_TransferComplete[channel] = false;
  DMAC->CHCTRLA.reg |= DMAC_CHCTRLA_ENABLE;
}
```

Setup CRC calculation:

```
/** \brief Initialize CRC module
 *
 * \param
 * \param
 * \return Nothing
 *
 */
void DMA_InitCRC(void)
{
  /**< Power on timer */
  MCLK->APBCMASK.reg |= DMA_CRC_TIMER_MCLK;
  GCLK->PCHCTRL[DMA_CRC_TIMER_GCLK_ID].reg = GCLK_PCHCTRL_GEN_GCLK0_Val | (1 << GCLK_PCHCTRL_CHEN_Pos);
  /**< Setup timer for 100usec events */
  DMA_CRC_TIMER->COUNT8.CTRLA.reg = TC_CTRLA_SWRST;
  while (DMA_CRC_TIMER->COUNT8.SYNCBUSY.reg & TC_SYNCBUSY_SWRST);
  DMA_CRC_TIMER->COUNT8.CTRLA.reg |= (DMA_CRC_TIMER_PRESCALER << TC_CTRLA_PRESCALER_Pos) | TC_CTRLA_MODE_COUNT8;
  DMA_CRC_TIMER->COUNT8.CTRLBSET.bit.DIR = 0;
  DMA_CRC_TIMER->COUNT8.PER.reg = DMA_CRC_TIMER_TICK;
  DMA_CRC_TIMER->COUNT8.COUNT.reg = 0;
  DMA_CRC_TIMER->COUNT8.CTRLA.reg |= (TC_CTRLA_ENABLE);

  DMAC->CTRL.reg &= ~DMAC_CTRL_CRCENABLE;
  /**< Configure the CRC engine */
  DMAC_CRCCTRL_Type crcctrl =
  {
    .bit.CRCSRC = DMAC_CRCCTRL_CRCSRC_IO_Val, /* I/O interface */
    .bit.CRCPOLY = DMAC_CRCCTRL_CRCPOLY_CRC16_Val, /* CRC-16 (CRC-CCITT)  */
    .bit.CRCBEATSIZE = DMAC_CRCCTRL_CRCBEATSIZE_BYTE_Val, /* Byte bus access */
  };
  DMAC->CRCCTRL.reg = crcctrl.reg;
}
```

Start new CRC calculation:

```
/** \brief Start CRC conversion
 *
 * \param [in] crc_init CRC initial value
 * \return Nothing
 *
 */
void DMA_StartCRC(uint32_t crc_init)
{
  /**< Clear the busy bit */
  DMAC->CRCSTATUS.bit.CRCBUSY = 1;
  DMAC->CTRL.bit.CRCENABLE = 0;
  /**< Initialize start CRC value for the CRC16 */
  DMAC->CRCCHKSUM.reg = crc_init;
  /**< Enable the CRC engine */
  DMAC->CTRL.bit.CRCENABLE = 1;
}
```

Get result of CRC calculation:

```
/** \brief Get CRC result from DMA module
 *
 * \return CRC as uint16_t
 *
 */
uint16_t DMA_GetCRC(void)
{
  return (uint16_t)DMAC->CRCCHKSUM.reg;
}
```

And now the source code of the thread with CRC calculation (I am using FreeRTOS):

```
  /**< CRC initialization */
  DMA_InitCRC();

  /**< Setup DMA channel for transmission */
  DmaSett.beat_size = DMAC_BTCTRL_BEATSIZE_BYTE_Val;
  DmaSett.trig_src = TC1_DMAC_ID_OVF;
  DmaSett.dst_addr = (void*)&DMAC->CRCDATAIN.reg;
  DmaSett.src_addr = APP_ADDRESS;
  DmaSett.src_inc = true;
  DmaSett.dst_inc = false;
  DmaSett.len = addr;
  DmaSett.priority = 0;
  DMA_SetupChannel(DMA_CHANNEL_CRC, &DmaSett);

  DMA_StartCRC(CRC16_INIT_VAL);

  DMA_StartChannel(DMA_CHANNEL_CRC);

  while (1)
  {
    // some periodical actions
    // ...

    if (DMA_IsReady(DMA_CHANNEL_CRC) == true)
    {
      crc = DMA_GetCRC();
      DMA_StartCRC(CRC16_INIT_VAL);
      DMA_StartChannel(DMA_CHANNEL_CRC);
      // do something with CRC here
      // ...
    }
  }
```

Does anybody have any experiences with DMA module of ATSAMC21? Actually it runs normally with UART, but I can't solve this problem with CRC interaction for some days already.

I will be grateful for any ideas!

Comment: Could it be something as silly as DMA_CHANNEL_CRC coinciding with one of your other DMA channels, or DMA_CHANNELS_NUM not accouting for the CRC channel??

Comment: No, I have tested everything twice before posting the problem. I haven't found any solution, I calculate the CRC with a DSU module now, it works seamless.